# .closest() to take a hidden div value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a question related on how to take the id value of a tag html closest to the element thats has been clicked, the problem is the element where are talking is far away in the html and is also hidden.
This is the html :

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="address_AddressList">
    <div style="margin-bottom:15px">
        <a class="btnAddAdress btn-primary btn btn-labeled" href="#" id="btnAddAdress" title="Nueva dirección"><span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-plus fa"></i></span>Nueva dirección</a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default address containerAddresses" id="0" data-placeinlist="0">

        <div class="panel-heading">

        </div>

        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseAssignedArea0">
            <div class="panel-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default address containerAddresses" id="1" data-placeinlist="1">

        <div class="panel-heading">

        </div>

        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseAssignedArea1" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="AreasContainer" data-urlgetareas="/location/getareas" data-urlsearchareas="/location/searchareas">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Nueva direccion-->
<div>
    <div class="panel-group address_newAddress hidden">
        <div class="panel panel-default address">

            <div class="panel-heading">

            </div>

            <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="collapseAssignedArea2">
                <div class="panel-body">


                    <div class="row margin-top-10">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <a class="btn btn-default col-md-12 btnAgregarAddress" data-url="/resource/updateaddresslistadminview" href="#" id="btnSaveAddress" title="Agregar"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up "></i> Agregar</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <a class="btn btn-danger col-md-12" href="#" id="btnCancelAddress" title="Cancelar"><i class="fa fa-ban "></i> Cancelar</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And what I want is to take the id value of the last of these divs:

```
$(".panel.panel-default.address.containerAddresses")
```

I have tried these:

```
$('.btn.btn-default.col-md-12.btnAgregarAddress')
    .closest(".panel.panel-default.address.containerAddresses")

$('.btn.btn-default.col-md-12.btnAgregarAddress')
    .closest(".panel.panel-default.address.containerAddresses")
    .siblings("div:hidden").attr("id");

$('.btn.btn-default.col-md-12.btnAgregarAddress')
    .closest(".panel.panel-default.address[div:hidden]")
```

So what I want is this: 
1) from this selector: `<a class="btn btn-default col-md-12 btnAgregarAddress"`
2) take the id of tha last `<div class="panel panel-default address containerAddresses"... </div>`
It is clear??
How I can get the value of the last(the first element above the clicked one) ?

Comment: Maybe the prev() can help you https://api.jquery.com/prev/ I wish your code was simplified and easily readable as I have trouble understanding exactly what you are going for

Comment: What's the starting point? What's being clicked?

Comment: I clicked from here `panel-group address_newAddress hidden`

Comment: @Huangism  take a look now please, let me know is it is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your given code, you can target it like this from where you have clicked. You could also target that by using `#address_AddressList` ID. I am not sure what the requirements are. Honestly, if you put a class or ID on the container div(at highest level without any identifiers), it would make this a lot easier, or target using that ID i mentioned before

```js
$(".btnAgregarAddress").on("click", function() {
  var targetID = $(this).closest(".panel-group").parent().prev().find(".containerAddresses").last().get(0).id;
  
  // this also works and it is better
  var targetID2 = $("#address_AddressList").find(".containerAddresses").last().get(0).id; 
  
  console.log( targetID );
  console.log( targetID2 );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group" id="address_AddressList">
  <div style="margin-bottom:15px">
    <a class="btnAddAdress btn-primary btn btn-labeled" href="#" id="btnAddAdress" title="Nueva dirección"><span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-plus fa"></i></span>Nueva dirección</a>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default address containerAddresses" id="0" data-placeinlist="0">

    <div class="panel-heading">

    </div>

    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseAssignedArea0">
      <div class="panel-body">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default address containerAddresses" id="1" data-placeinlist="1">

    <div class="panel-heading">

    </div>

    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseAssignedArea1" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
      <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="AreasContainer" data-urlgetareas="/location/getareas" data-urlsearchareas="/location/searchareas">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Nueva direccion-->
<div>
  <div class="panel-group address_newAddress hidden">
    <div class="panel panel-default address">

      <div class="panel-heading">
      </div>

      <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="collapseAssignedArea2">
        <div class="panel-body">

          <div class="row margin-top-10">
            <div class="col-md-10">
              <a class="btn btn-default col-md-12 btnAgregarAddress" data-url="/resource/updateaddresslistadminview" href="#" id="btnSaveAddress" title="Agregar"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up "></i> Agregar</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="btn btn-danger col-md-12" href="#" id="btnCancelAddress" title="Cancelar"><i class="fa fa-ban "></i> Cancelar</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh really thank you, my problem that I was trying to take that value from a forced position. didnt know I could do shuch things(decide for my self wherer to start to find()),  you opened a new wordl for me!!, really  thank you!!! :D . Finally I decided to take not the id, the data-attr like this: `$("#address_AddressList").find(".containerAddresses").last().get(0).dataset.placeinlist` , do you think its the recomendable way, using dataset?, thank you @Huangism

Comment: If you need the value of a data attribute, you use `.data()` please take a look at https://api.jquery.com/data/ it is very easy to use